# gene expression datamatrix filtration

Tags: r

I have one matrix with `3064` rows and `27` columns which contains values between `-0.5` and `2.0`. I want to extract every rows which have at least once value `>=0.5`. As answer I would like to have whole row in it's origional matrix form.

Consider `m` is my matrix, I tried:

```
m[m[1:190,1:16]>0.5,1:16]
```

As this command is not accepting process on more then 190 rows, I went for 190 rows, but somehow it went wrong, because it gave me rows which also have *values < 0.5*.

Is it possible to write any function, that can be applied for whole matrix ?

Comment: If you need rows with at least one value >=0.5, try  `m[rowSums(m >=0.5)>0,]`

Comment: i want to have matrix,whithout row that contain value "< 0.5 "

Comment: But your description `I want to extract every row , which have at least once value >=0.5 in his row.` in the post is opposite to what you mention in the comments.  Anyway, do consider to show a small example `(10 rows, 5 columns) and expected result based on that.

Comment: If you don't want rows that contain value < 0.5, then `m[!rowSums(m <0.5),]`

Comment: i just tried, it gave me name of column as answer

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to comment.  Anyway, I tried with an example created and it gave the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try like this if your data name is ***df***

```
df2<- df[apply(df, MARGIN = 1, function(x) any(x >= 0.5)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(fBasics)
m2 <- subset(x = m, subset = rowMaxs(m)>=0.5)
```

Comment: It's just the name of the argument. You can leave it out (and just use `subset(m, subset=...)`, but see `?subset` to get a better understanding of parameter passing in R.

Answer (score 1):

What `mm=m[1:190,1:16]>0.5` gives you is a matrix of boolean indicating which values of `m[1:190,1:16]` are greater than 0.5.

Then when you do `m[mm]`, it considers `mm` as a vector and gives you corresponding values. The thing is `dim(m) = 3064*27` while `dim(m[1:190,1:16]) = 190*16`. Which means that the first 27 values of `mm` will be used to get the first line of `m` while they correspond to part of the second line of `mm`.

So in order to have only the elements greater than 0.5, you need to apply `matrix` to `m[1:190,1:16]` which has the same dimension, i.e:

```
`m[1:190,1:16][m[1:190,1:16]>0.5, 1:16]
```

But what you do here is `m[mm, 1:16]`, so you consider each individual value of `mm` as a row number, while it is a 190*16 matrix. It means you specify `190*16=3040` rows, it does not work with more because `m` only has `3064` rows.

What you want is a vector of length 190 (or even 3064 I guess) specifying which rows to take. You can get this vector with `rowSums(m >=0.5)>0`, which means each row with more than 0 values greater than 0.5. Then you get your output with:

```
m[rowSums(m >= 0.5) > 0,]
```

And it will work for the whole matrix. Note that some values will be smaller than 0.5 since you selected the whole line if at least one value was greater than 0.5.

*Edit*

For rows with values `<0.5`, the idea is the same:

```
m[rowSums(m < 0.5) > 0,]
```